# Java, ObjectOutputStream.writeObject prints random symbols to file

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

```
public class Customer {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         FileOutputStream a = new FileOutputStream("customer.txt");
         ObjectOutputStream b = new ObjectOutputStream(a);

         human Iman = new human("Iman",5000);
         human reda = new human("reda",5555);

         b.writeObject(Iman);   //prints random symbols. 
         b.writeObject(reda);     
    }
}

class human implements Serializable{
        private String name;
        private double balance;

        public human(String n,double b){
            this.name=n;
            this.balance=b;
        }
}
```

What do these random symbols represent?

Comment: Yes, Serializable writes the objects out in a machine readable format. It is not meant to be read by you, it is meant to be read back by a Java program. If you want to output it in a human readable fashion, you will have to write your own output logic using the `FileOutputStream` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are trying to store the object itself and hence binary format is getting stored.

To actually store the data in text format, use below code BufferedWriter as below:

```
public void writeHumanStateToFile(Human human){
          try{
            File file = new File("filename.txt");


            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(human.getName);
            bw.write(human.getBalance);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
           }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
```

I am assuming you want to persist the state of Human object.

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). That doesn't produce text - it produces a *binary* serialized version of the data. If you really need a text representation, you'll need to use a different approach.

If you're fine with it being binary data though, leave it as it is - but perhaps change the filename to be less misleading. You can read the data again with [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Answer (score 2):

The data format is described in the [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) document. As you've noted, it's not human-readable.

If you want to serialize in a readable format, you might be able to use `java.beans.XMLEncoder`, or something like [Pojomatic](http://www.pojomatic.org).

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing the object.  It is not meant to be readable in plain text, but to be a binary format that makes it easy to read the object and recreate it in a later execution of the program.

If you want to store your objects in plain text, then you need to write the individual fields of your object to the file.